# Spring-Boot Docker This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm doing a little project and I have this controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Value("${me}")
    private String name;

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User created = userService.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(created, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public String me() {
        return "hello " + name;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        User user = userService.getByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

When working in localhost all my endpoints are working fine but when I dockerized it, "/hello" and "/me" endpoints return

```
**This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/user/hello
HTTP ERROR 404**
```

What's the reason of it not working?

EDIT: I've been asked to add Dockerfile and here is my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/elasticSpring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar elasticSpring.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/elasticSpring.jar" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '1'
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.12
    container_name: es
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - mynet

  springboot-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: springElastic
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - spring.elasticsearch.uris=es:9200
      - spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=es:9200
    depends_on:
      - es
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

And it works locally but when I start my application with docker-compose.yml endpoints "/user/hello" and "/user/me" says "This localhost page can’t be found" other endpoints work and has no problem.

Comment: You say the code you've included works, but there are no details on how exactly you've made it run in a container.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; for example, your Dockerfile, how you started the container, and what specific URL you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Can you share your `docker run` command? Probably you're missing port mapping. It should look like: `docker run -p 8080:8080 yourimage`

Comment: I added the details you require. And no, I did not miss port mapping.

Comment: I don't see any problem but i guess it's because of your `bridge` network. Remove the networks you defined in your compose file because the services in the compose file are in the same network. Also when you trying to connect to your elasticsearch from your spring app, you don't need to expose the elasticsearch port. Hope it helps !